# How to apply parameters/for loop

Tags: python, variables, for-loop, vector, parameters

Currently I have a program that finds the dot product of two XYZ coordinates, how would I put this into a loop, so that it goes down a list of coordinates and finds the dot product of each coordinate relative to the first one.

```
import operator

vector1 = (int(l[0][0]),int(l[0][1]),int(l[0][2]))
vector2 = (int(l[1][0]),int(l[1][1]),int(l[1][2]))
dotProduct = reduce(operator.add, map(operator.mul, vector1, vector2))
print dotProduct
```

So I want the first vector to stay constant but the second vector to change, from `int(l[1][0]),int(l[1][1]),int(l[1][2])` to the next coordinate which would be `int(2[1][0]),int(2[1][1]),int(2[1][2])`.

I am a beginner using Python so I know this might be a very simple answer but any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
l=[]
with open("coordinate_test") as f:
    line = f.next()
    nat = int(line.split()[0])
  print nat
  f.next()# skip headers
  for line in f:
      if line.strip():
        l.append(map(float,line.split()[1:]))  # make all values floats   
print l[0][0]


import operator
import numpy as np
vector1 = (int(l[0][0]),int(l[0][1]),int(l[0][2]))
vector2 = (int(l[a][0]),int(l[a][1]),int(l[a][2]))
print vector1
print vector2
x = vector1
y = vector2
vector3 = list(np.array(x) - np.array(y))
print vector3
dotProduct = reduce( operator.add, map( operator.mul, vector3, vector3))
print dotProduct
```

So I have the variable nat, which is the number of times I want the dot product loop to run (stuff under import operator), but how do I make that run that many times and how can i Make the variable "a" go up by one everytime, and How do i set a starting value for that variable "a".

Thanks.

Comment: you should use actual numeric values rather than some unknown l variable

Comment: As a comment, the dot product in a more pythonic form is: `sum(x1 * x2 for x1, x2 in zip(vector1, vector2))`

Comment: or `numpy.dot` for super terse :P

Comment: def dotproduct(vec1, vec2):
    return sum(imap(operator.mul, vec1, vec2))  #also pretty python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import operator

vector1 = (1, 2, 3)

# get a list of vectors
vectors = [
    (4, 5, 6),
    (7, 8, 9)
]

# for loop through the vectors,
# assignig the current vector to vector2 in every iteration
for vector2 in vectors:
    dotProduct = reduce(operator.add, map(operator.mul, vector1, vector2))
    print dotProduct
```

Using your `l`, `nat` and `a` variables:

```
vector1 = (int(l[0][0]), int(l[0][1]), int(l[0][2]))

for a in range(1, nat):
    vector2 = (int(l[a][0]), int(l[a][1]), int(l[a][2]))
    dotProduct = reduce(operator.add, map(operator.mul, vector1, vector2))
    print(dotProduct)
```

Comment: +1 for giving him basically his code back fixed :) there is probably much more educational value in that than my answer :)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Well yes, that's the level of many questions these days :| Thanks for numpy way!

Comment: Would I have to manually insert all the coordinates into my code?

Comment: @Wana_B3_Nerd Of course not, we can use the `l` variable, now that we know what it is :) Added a more specific example using your variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy
v0 = (6,7,6)
vectors = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
dot_products = vectors.dot(v0)
```

is by far the easiest way to do what you are trying to do imho

and it should be much faster if you have "a lot" of vectors in your vectors list...(for some definition of a lot)