# Need Help solving a basic for loop

Tags: python, math, for-loop

Currently i have a program that finds coordinates makes them into lists and performs the dot product function on them, I have recently tried to add in a loop so that it runs through the program x amount of times performing the operation with all the coordinates, but I can't seem to get it to make it run through all the data and display all the answers, here is my code, it is very basic as I am a beginner programmer:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


l=[]
with open("coordinate_test") as f:
line = f.next()
nat = int(line.split()[0])
print nat
f.next()# skip headers
for line in f:
    if line.strip():
        l.append(map(float,line.split()[1:]))  # make all values floats   
#print l[0][0]

a = 1
for a in range(0,nat): 
import operator
import numpy as np
vector1 = (int(l[0][0]),int(l[0][1]),int(l[0][2]))
vector2 = (int(l[a][0]),int(l[a][1]),int(l[a][2]))
#print vector1
#print vector2
x = vector1
y = vector2
vector3 = list(np.array(x) - np.array(y))
#print vector3
dotProduct = reduce( operator.add, map( operator.mul, vector3, vector3))
print dotProduct
a += 1
print a
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong; perhaps that is why your program doesn't work?

Comment: Add example data add expected result.

Comment: You will need to manually add more groups of four spaces to show the same indentation in your post.

Comment: ummm .... are you in this guys class ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660923/how-to-apply-parameters-for-loop/24661274#24661274

Comment: Wow that actually was the problem! Thanks, who would have thought that would make such a big error.

Comment: Or paste your code again and use button `{}`

Comment: @joran Beasley not same classs, same person :P

Comment: ahh gotcha ... I thought that code looked very familiar

Comment: btw does python not use the < or > in its language?

Comment: Okay seriously, what class are you guys in, is this some high school or is there a University out there that's teaching this?  1) Apparently indentation was not very important, 2) Import statements inside of loops? 3) What's with `a = 1` right before the `for a in...`?

Comment: @Wana_B3_Nerd python uses both greater than and less than symbols `><` also for middle school that code is not that horrible ... but work at learning the fundamentals :P

Comment: I was just confused because when I was making the parameters for the for loop range a < 56 wouldn't work but (0,56) does.

Comment: `for i in range(56)` is equivelent to `for(i=0;i<56;i++)` in C ...try something like `5 < 8`  or even more than 1 compare `x=7;3 < x <9` comparison operators are used in comparisons not in iterations

Comment: Okay never mind, I'm being too harsh then.  Don't give up in that case because you're already way ahead of the curve.

Comment: So now I have one for loop working, now I have to add another loop... :( to get a loop inside of a loop.